# How to get the predicted class instead of class probabilities?

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I have trained a random forest using `caret` package for predicting a binary classification task.

```
library(caret)
set.seed(78)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(disambdata$Response, p=3/4, list = FALSE)
trainSet <- disambdata[inTrain,]
testSet <- disambdata[-inTrain,]
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 10)
grid_rf <- expand.grid(.mtry = c(3,5,7,9))
set.seed(78)
m_rf <- train(Response ~ ., data=trainSet, 
          method= "rf", metric = "Kappa", trcontrol=ctrl, tuneGrid = grid_rf)
```

The `Response` variable contains values {`Valid`, `Invalid`}. 
Using the following I get the class probabilities for the testing data:

```
pred <- predict.train(m_rf, newdata = testSet, 
                  type="prob", models=m_rf$finalModel)
```

However **I am interested in obtaining the predicted class** i.e. `Valid` or `Invalid` **instead of class probabilities** to **generate a confusion matrix**.

I have already tried the argument `type="raw"` in the `predict.train` function but it returns a list of `NAs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the caret package (caret_6.0-70) still has issue with the formula interface. Expanding the formula from `Response ~ .` to the one that explicitly mentions all predictors like this `Response ~ MaxLikelihood + n1 + n2 + count` resolves the problem and `predict.train(m_rf, newdata=testSet)` returns the predicted class.

Comment: If it is a bug, report it on the github page of caret.

Comment: @phiver, yes i do plan to report it, as it was reported for one of the previous versions of the package caret too. The release notes of the version I have (6.0-70) mention that this issue has been addressed. Anyways I will report the bug on github

Answer (score 3):

By assigning type = "prob" in predict() function, you are specifically asking for probabilities. just remove it & it will provide labels

```
pred <- predict.train(m_rf, newdata = testSet,models=m_rf$finalModel)
```

Comment: unfortunately its not working for me, removing `type=prob` does no good. the `pred` receives `NAs`